# How to generate 3D shape/plane from 2d pixel points/map?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl

For a 2d grey image, I want to extract each pixel's grey/brightness value as depth/z-index to generate a smooth 3d plane, something like a brightness level depth map.

My simple idea is that loop add each pixel as a point in the scene, and set z-index with grey value. 
But, first how to add points(a very small one to represent a pixel) with Three.js?
And, is this a good way? is this a smooth plane? what if a large image(e.g. 2000*4800, I don't think memory can hold that much points)?

Comment: Look for the `displacementMap` parameter of a material.

Comment: See: http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html Essentially, plane geometry is utilized with the number of vertexes you need, which is the pixel size of your depth map. A loop takes the pixel value and converts it to a z position of the vertex. Smoothing can be achieved with materials or interpolation.